# Mouseover Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I'm making a little site and I'm trying to get the text to change when I mouseover it but it's not working, can anyone tell me why?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <head><center>
              <script type = "text/javascript">
                  function changeText(msg) {
                  var targetDiv = document.getElementById("changeDIV");
                  if (msg == "A") {
                  targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover="changeText('B')"> Please work sadface</h1></p>";
                  } else if (msg == "B") {
                  targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover="changeText('A')"> Irish Presidents Wiki </h1></p>";
                  }
                  }

             </script>
             </center>
             </head>




          <body><center>

              <div id = "changeDIV"><p><h1 onmouseover = "changeText('A')">Irish Presidents Wiki</h1></p></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is caused by the wrong formatted double quotes, try this:

```
         <script type = "text/javascript">
              function changeText(msg) {
              var targetDiv = document.getElementById("changeDIV");
              if (msg == "A") {
              targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover=\"changeText('B')\"> Please work sadface</h1></p>";
              } else if (msg == "B") {
              targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover=\"changeText('A')\"> Irish Presidents Wiki </h1></p>";
              }
              }

         </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I'd looked over something.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above:

```
<div id="changeDIV">
    <p>
        <h1 onMouseOver="changeText('A');">Irish Presidents Wiki</h1>
    </p>
</div>
```

Ommit space before and after `=`

```
function changeText(msg) {

    var targetDiv = document.getElementById("changeDIV");
    if (msg == "A") {
        targetDiv.innerHTML = "y";
    } else if (msg == "B") {
        targetDiv.innerHTML = "x";
    }
}
```

onMouseOver is CaMeLcAsE

forgot: jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nv4f8/)

Answer (score 0):

First try to work clear. This is very important in every programming language.

Second important thing is: No, do not use `<center>` in `<head>` because `<center>` is only can be used in `body` which is about visual side of your website.

And here is your solution:

```
<html>

  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function changeText(msg) {
              var targetDiv = document.getElementById("changeDIV");
              if (msg == "A") {
                  targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover=\"changeText('B')\"> Please work sadface</h1></p>";
              } else if (msg == "B") {
                  targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover=\"changeText('A')\"> Irish Presidents Wiki </h1></p>";
              }
          }
      </script>
  </head>




  <body>
      <center>

          <div id="changeDIV">
              <p>
                  <h1 onmouseover="changeText('A')">Irish Presidents Wiki</h1>
              </p>
          </div>
      </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

But also your error is also important because you have to improve yourself to be good.

```
targetDiv.innerHTML = "<p><h1 onmouseover=\"changeText('B')\"> Please work sadface</h1></p>";
```

You can't use `"` , `'` in a string with starting with the same type.

You started your string variable with `"` == `targetDiv.innerHTML = "`

If you add `"` at `onmouseover="changeText('B')">` your script wont work. Because you are ending your declaration with the `"`.

So if you want to use `"` as a string use escape character like I did. `\"`

Now compiler will take `"` as a string not a declaration end character.